# How To Specify Default Text Cursor Widget in QT Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have a window with multiple line edit widgets, allowing the user to enter text in multiple input fields.

However when I run the application, the text cursor position defaults to the last input field, rather than the first field.

I would instead like the text cursor to default to the first widget upon opening the application, so that the user can immediately start typing into the first field without having to manually select that field.

I have specified the first widget as the first tab order, however does not seem to make a difference.

Is there an option in QT designer where I can specify the default widget for the cursor when opening the application?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - I believe the function is called [setFocus()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus-1)

I added this to the widget which I wanted to have keyword cursor focus, and the keyboard cursor sucessfully defaulted to this widget upon opening the window.